# ListFragment with 600 Pages Book

Tags: android

I have implemented a ListFragment that do the following:

1- Load image files (Pages) into a List< Page >. (files are from sdcard app-private directory)

2- Create a ListAdapter and pass the List< Page > object to it.

3- setListAdapter to ListFragment.

```
public class QReadingFragment extends ListFragment {
    private Context context;

    public QReadingFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        new QLoadPagesTask().execute(context.getExternalFilesDir(null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }

    private class QLoadPagesTask extends AsyncTask<File, String, List<? extends QPage>> {

        @Override
        protected List<? extends QPage> doInBackground(File... files) {
            return QPageContract.preparePages(files[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<? extends QPage> pages) {
            setListAdapter(new QReadingAdapter(context, pages));
        }
    }
}
```

QReadingAdapter implements a ListAdapter and its getView returns imageView object.

My problem is that loading all 600 pages (images) causes my app to close:

> Unfortunatly, APP has stopped.

I have tried loading 10 pages only, the app runs without any issues.

So I decided to use AsyncTask (with largeHeap="true") to load all the 600 iages at once, I still get same issue.

UPDATES:

Now my ListFragment loads the first 10 pages, when the user scroll down the ListFragment loads next pages but while I am scrolling down to reach 600 pages android closes the app because of memory limits.

What I am trying now is to load on the following pages into the ListFragment:

- First Visible Page
- Two Pages Prior the "First Visible Page"
- Two Pages After the "First Visible Page"

all other items on the listFragment must be assigned the stub image.

Comment: use smaller images and look at this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Is there a better approach? I am thinking of loading images on demand, while user scrolling up and down pages are get loaded. (These images are book pages and I need to display them in correct order too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to have an Adapter that can accommodate a maximum of say 10 items. and check for the last visible item in `onScroll(AbsListView, int, int,int)` of `onScrollListener`.. Then, when you're reaching the end, load the next 10 items in the adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: What if the user scrolled too fast down... Let say, he wanted to go to the last chapter.

Comment: Ok, So just show stub images and not the original book pages when scroll state is SCROLL_STATE_FLING, and when it changes to SCROLL_STATE_IDLE get the visible item position and show the real pages of those very positions.. You can get the scroll state in onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)

Comment: Further reed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged(android.widget.AbsListView, int)